# Is there any “wave equation” analogous to Schrodinger’s Equation in QFT?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, wavefunction

As in, is there any sort of partial differential equation, for let’s say, a real scalar field qft theory that you could solve for a wave function that describes the qft?

Comment: I’ve seen some stuff about “wave functionals” but I didn’t really understand it.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/367160

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger_functional see also the first book referenced there.

Comment: possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/214552/84967

Comment: [Linked illustration](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/395051/energies-of-this-field-hamiltonian?noredirect=1&lq=1) of tractable case.